# How to estimate if an old AC is worth replacing?

Tags: air-conditioning, energy-efficiency

Have a window AC unit that's from 2001, here are the specs:

- **Manufacturer:** Kenmore
- **VOLTS:** 115
- **Cooling BTU/HR:** 12500
- **Cooling AMPS:** 11.6
- **Cooling WATTS:** 1275
- **Cooling EER:** 9.8

The average electricity rate is 11.04¢/kWh.

As for the hours of use per day, currently varies anywhere from 12 to 24 hours of use per day, so I'm not sure how to deal with that; maybe the easiest way is to just do two estimates, one for 12 hours of use, and another for 24 hours of use.

User Manual is [here](http://www.searspartsdirect.com/partsdirect/user-manuals/6790/25370125003-Kenmore-Parts-ROOM+A@SLASH@C-manual?pathRender=fromManualTabPage).

Very possible that I've left out some information, but even with the above information, I still haven't been able to figure out how to even do a rough comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EER (energy efficiency ratio) is a lovely mashup of units (BTU/h)/Watts (ie, 12500/1275 in the questioned case) that will tell you (part of) what you need to know. The rest is up to how much you run it.

It uses 1.275 KWh/h (1275 watts) and that costs you 14.07 cents/hr at 11.04 cents/KWh

Compare to whatever you think you might replace it with - you'd want a higher EER than 9.8, or you could just look at 12500 BTU models and compare watts directly. Less watts costs you less per hour to run - if they are all cooling by the same amount (12500 BTU/hr) then the lowest watts is the most efficient and should have the highest EER as well.

A low-effort search (ie you might find better) shows a current EER of 11.3 on one similar new unit. If exactly equivalent in BTU/h that would be 1106 watts, or 1.106 KWh/h, or 12.21 cents per hour, or a savings of slightly less than 2 cents per operating hour.

If willing to step away from the window-unit format you may be able to get much better EER in a mini-split type system, but it will likely cost more up front.